# Precompiling MVC ASP.NET application via publish, Are the resultant files IL Code or Native Images?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Just wanted to check whether the precompiled files from "publish" are IL or Native. The file extension are .compiled for the views, and dlls for others.

I have seen some comment that imply that one of the advantages for doing this is to eliminate startup lag due to JIT, but this implies that they are native, but I am not sure.

I have chosed "no merging" of files for my first attempt.

Confirmation appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT

Is there any potential difference if I select x86, or "mixed platforms" or "any cpu". The latter 2 might imply IL code whereas x86 could be native. I am targetting a 32bit Azure Websites instance. I am trying to get rid of the warmup period issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is IL.  You can confirm it by running [CorFlags.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(v=vs.110).aspx). The CorFlags section of the header of a portable executable image will indicate whether its 32bit or AnyCPU etc. Another utility that comes in handy is [DUMPBIN.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx).

Even if you precompile your web applications, there's going to be an initial hit when you access the website.  That process is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163496.aspx). Its a tad dated, but much of it still applies.  But the hit with a precompiled website is going to be substantially less than a non-precompiled website.

When compiling, select "Any CPU" and control whether its a 32bit or 64bit application via IIS, Azure or the hosting environment. Let the framework do what the framework does best.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will and have a read and get back to you. Out of interest, do you have a view on whether it is worthwhile, or possible, using NGEN to create native code upfront, for deployment into Azure Websites?

Comment: Running NGEN may be worth it, but do it on the target machine (e.g. when you install the application), not during build.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate this. Is it possible to do on Azure websites?

Comment: I have no idea whether its possible.